# Useless column appear on binding

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I have this Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="GridBinding" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[record]}" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10" Width="497">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[LastName].Value}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sales" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Sales].Value}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Country].Value}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quarter" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Quarter].Value}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And this on the constructor

```
XElement TrackList = XElement.Load("Rock_None.xml");
        GridBinding.DataContext = TrackList;
```

My problem is, when I load it up, all the xml binding is ok but I have other column as  attribute, element, descendant ... Appearing and I don't know why, I could use some help

Comment: Do you need to set the autogeneratecolumns property of the data grid to false?

Comment: Well that did it, but it's really unpleasent of them to autogenerate like that.... it should always be false and if we need it it's true...

Comment: It's been like that forever but I tend to agree with you as most of the time you probably I set to false anyway so as to keep fairly tight control on the visuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, you will need to set the AutoGenerateColumns of the data grid to false, otherwise it will then append then to your defined list.

(Sorry, can't post example as on a tablet)